# Why can't I downvote my own answer?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, down-votes

I understand why I can't upvote my own answer, but if I realise that my answer is wrong, why can't I downvote it?

Also, for one answer, I figured I'd just edit saying something to the effect of "warning - this answer is wrong - left in as a warning to others". This seems like the right (but embarrassing) thing to do - but is it?

Basically, what's the normal way to confess your own wrong answers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delete it if it's wrong and off base.

By deleting, you help clean up by not littering with an incorrect answer (unless you're a mod and you get the joys of seeing deleted answers amidst the non-deleted).

Comment: Note that you can't delete it if it's been accepted...

Answer (score 4):

If it doesn't solve the exact question posted but could potentially be useful to someone else who comes across that question with a *similar* problem, I sometimes mark the answer as community wiki with a note saying that it's wrong but potentially applicable.

Of course, if it's completely wrong and not at all applicable, then as @random points out, deleting it is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand-- if your answer is wrong, why you don't just correct it?

Comment: You can realise it's wrong, without knowing what the right answer is

Comment: @Ralph - in that case delete it. If you later realise what the correct answer is you can go back to the question, edit your answer and undelete it.

Comment: You can also realise that other peoples answers are right, or better. Why add noise?