# Downvote own answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, voting, down-votes

When you post an answer, you usually get a couple of votes. But then another user may post a better answer, appearing at the bottom of the page. Of course I then up-vote it, but I sometimes feel like down-voting my own too, as it often covers a less important aspect. This would help new good answers to faster move to the top.

What answer is most relevant is the community's job to determine, but I am part of the community too. Up-voting your own question would of course be a bad feature, but maybe down-voting it can actually be a good thing? To give room for a new, better, answer?

Not the same question as [Why can't I downvote my own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24813/why-cant-i-downvote-my-own-answer), because that is more about what you should do if you find out that your answer is wrong. I am thinking more about that the answer is good enough as it is, just that another new answer includes a couple of extra important points.

Comment: Seems like some people are helping me to down-vote this question too :P

Comment: Why don't you just improve your own answer....instead of down voting it?

Comment: @Ramhound That is not always necessary, as the other answer may cover all that is needed. But Improving an answer is always something to consider.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can always just delete your answer; it doesn't even have to be a bad answer - if you think someone else has done a wholly better job, then deferring to them is an honorable thing to do. [There's even a badge for it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined)...

I'd caution you against deleting your answer (or doing anything else to discourage folks from reading it) if you've taken a very different approach to explaining the solution - it may be that your answer will be useful to folks who struggle to interpret the new answer.

One approach I've used in the past is to [edit unique aspects of your explanation into the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/766128/revisions), and then delete your answer. Be sure to explain (in revision notes) *why* you're doing this, and always try to achieve a consistent tone in the resulting text (don't just tack on a code sample, integrate it into the answer with some explanation). This offers the best of both worlds, IMHO - nothing of value is lost, while the value of reader's time is maximized.

Answer (score 5):

There's very little to gain from adding such a feature, as there already exist alternatives to clarification (support or disapproval) through voting. My suggestion would be to

1. add a comment clarifying why you consider your answer to be inferior to some other answer; or
2. edit your answer directly stating such.

If your answer is very poor, delete it altogether. If you really wish to keep some of the content, repost it as a comment instead.